# How can I stop Ingress from vibrating my phone?

Tags: ingress

Ingress activates the vibration on my Nexus 4 (with stock ROM) when the resonators carrousel is turning in the portal upgrade view. How can I stop it?

Comment: I feel your pain (G-S2).

Comment: You ask Google to **please** add an option to turn vibration off.

Answer (score 2):

The only option I can find for vibrations seems to be for *all* vibrations.

Under *Ops* - Device - Notifications

Uncheck Vibrate

Comment: Unchecking this option does nothing.

Comment: Cyntech - it totally worked for me